# How do I get env variables in Javascript?(webpack or roadhog)

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have two server IP: (1) and (2).

`var host = '(1) or (2)'`

I want to inject server ip automatically depends on what env currently is.

For instance if env is build then host = (1), if env is dev then host = (2).

`` fetch(`${host}/user`, options).then(...) ``

Comment: Can't you use process.env??